# copying Excel rows to sheets if date time cell falls between 0000 & 0600?

Tags: string, excel, copy, find, formula

How would I copy Excel rows to a new worksheet if a date time cell falls between 0000 & 0600 ?
For example, for 10,000+ rows of data, in Column J, there's a date/time stamp "1/15/2013 0245".
How do I create a formula which looks at the last 4 digits, check if it's <= 0000 and >= 0600, and reproduce that row on a new spreadsheet?

Comment: you mean 0 <= Time <= 6000 don't you?

Answer (score 0):

If the value in A1 is actually a date/time then create this formula and copy it down a column:

```
=IF(HOUR(A1)<=6,A1,"")
```

Use `<6` if you want to exclude 0600 and change "" for some other value.

If the value is treated as text, then:

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))<=600,A1,"")
```

which extracts the four characters on the right and converts them to a number (VALUE).

Answer (score 0):

For example you could Use `=IF(AND(RIGHT(A2,4)*1>=0,RIGHT(A2,4)*1<=600),"Yes","No")`

Then create a pivot table filtering on "Yes"